# Only allow a certain drive when using RDS drive redirection

Tags: windows, group-policy, rds, microsoft

I have an RDS farm setup on Windows Server 2012R2. The clients that use this RDS farm all come from the same network. There's a shared drive (let's call it `\\shared`) on this network that all the clients can use.

Currently I have a GPO policy `Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Device and Resource Redirection/Do not allow drive redirection` set to enabled. There's a new requirement, where instead the users should be allowed drive redirection just for the `\\shared` drive, but not for their local drives.

Is it somehow possible to do this via GPO or maybe other measures, like RDS config?

I know that a potential solution would be to permanently map the `\\shared` drive on the RDSH hosts, but there would be a lot of network issues doing this (if at all possible). I want to discount other options before I explore the world of hurt that this approach would entail.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to map the desired drive during logon. This will work for both local logon and RDP logon for all users.

A quick way to do this is to use a domain log on script:

1. Open notepad and type: **net use x:\\yourserver\shared.**
2. Save the file with a **.bat** extension.
3. Paste the batch file into the **sysvol** folder in the following location **C:\Windows\SYSYVOL\sysvol\\scripts** (or the drive\location that you designated for the SYSVOL folder during dcpromo).

This should do the job.

Comment: This would try to map the drives directly on the RDSH hosts, wouldn't it? The shared drive isn't available in the server environment, it's only available to the clients, because they come from a completely different network managed by someone else. That's why I wanted to use drive redirection.